# ImageComponent3D constructor wants an integer format and a BufferedImage[] array to be declared

Tags: java, arrays, constructor, bufferedimage

I have a code below constructs a `BufferedImage` object called bufferedImage which is 2D:

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(121, 400,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
bufferedImage.setRGB(a, b, Pixel);
```

I need to add a depth or a third dimension to this image by creating the object of `ImageComponent3D`. To construct an object of it, we may have a declaration as:

```
ImageComponent3D ic = new ImageComponent3D(int format, **java.awt.image.BufferedImage[] images**);
```

However, I do not have a `BufferedImage[]` but I have a `BufferedImage` as constructed in the first statement, which is supposed to be converted to a 3D image.

Can anyone help me about the relevance between the array object `BufferedImage[]` and the object `BufferedImage`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to supply only one image to this constructor, you could do

```
BufferedImage array[] = new BufferedImage[] {
    bufferedImage;
};
ImageComponent3D ic = new ImageComponent3D(format, array);
```

Comment: I need to convert BufferedImage to BufferedImage[] somehow, since the given data is stored in BufferedImage instead of creating a new instance of BufferedImage[]. Do I need instances of BufferedImage and at least 2 of them to be stored in the array of BufferedImage[] to use it as the parameter of new instance of an ImageComponent3D?

Comment: There is no new BufferedImage created in the code that I posted. A new array is created, but this array **contains** your original image. And it contains only 1 element (you can create arrays with arbitrary numbers of elements)